# Can the rate of descent be measured with a laser?

Tags: reentry, landing

Can a laser be used to measure the rate of descent of a re-entry probe during its re-entry into a planet's or satellite's atmosphere?

Are there any probes that used a laser to measure its descent?

Comment: Yes. There are laser, radar, and gamma-ray altimeters. Gamma-ray altimeters (with a Co-60 or Cs-137 IIRC pellet) are used in capsules, like the Soyuz or Shenzhou.

Comment: I suspect LIDAR is of limited use in an atmosphere. Cloud cover would mess up your altitude readings.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. This technology is commonly referred to as [LIDAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar) (Laser Image Detection and Ranging) and is a combination (portmanteau) of words *"light"* and *"radar"*:

> Lidar is popularly known as a technology used to make high resolution
>   maps, geomatics, archaeology, geography, geology, geomorphology,
>   seismology, forestry, remote sensing, atmospheric physics, airborne
>   laser swath mapping (ALSM), laser altimetry, and contour mapping.

As far as the use of LIDARs as altimeters in astronautics is concerned:

> The general public became aware of the accuracy and usefulness of
>   lidar systems in 1971 during the Apollo 15 mission, when astronauts
>   used a laser altimeter to map the surface of the moon.

They are also used by Earth orbiting satellites to produce digital elevation maps, [measure the distance to reflectors placed on the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_Experiment), Mars Global Surveyor uses LIDAR for precise global topographic surveys, Phoenix Lander to detect snow in the atmosphere of Mars,...

> Lidar is increasingly being utilized for range finding and orbital
>   element calculation of relative velocity in proximity operations and
>   station keeping of spacecraft. Lidar has also been used for
>   atmospheric studies from space. Using short pulses of laser light
>   beamed from a spacecraft, some of that "light reflects off of tiny
>   particles in the atmosphere and back to a telescope aligned with the
>   laser. By precisely timing the lidar 'echo,' and by measuring how much
>   laser light is received by the telescope, scientists can accurately
>   determine the location, distribution and nature of the particles. The
>   result is a revolutionary new tool for studying constituents in the
>   atmosphere, from cloud droplets to industrial pollutants, that are
>   difficult to detect by other means.

It is also used in robotic missions to determine distance to the ground, obstacles, e.t.c.

American Lunar probe [Clementine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clementine_%28spacecraft%29) (Deep Space Program Science Experiment) also used LIDAR system to measure the distance from the spacecraft to a point on the surface of the Moon.

Comment: I think the question is about determining vertical *velocity* rather than position.  Doppler lidar can do that, but how precise?

Comment: Doppler lidar is incredibly precise - measuring the frequency shift is very accurate.